# Is there hidden implication of using the coalesce or +0 hack to prevent blanks?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have multiple card visual showing measures.

When there is no value then the card shows (Blank).

To prevent this I see there are 2 choices:

1. COALESCE
2. +0

Which is these is a better alternative? Or is there any other alternative?

Does this lead to any hidden implication that could result in incorrect calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own COALESCE sort of statement that may be more readable to others.

```
IF ( ISBLANK ( X ), 0, X )
```

Note that `+ 0` doesn't work if you measure returns a string (but you could use `& ""` instead).

Comment: It will impact AVG calculations because AVG ignored blanks where as it will include 0s

Answer (score 0):

The issue with doing that is that it overrides the filters, so when you are showing something where you need the detail, PowerBI would automatically remove the blank values but if you force it to be 0 that doesn't work anymore.

For example, given this dataset Country and Fruit sales, with a relationship between Country table and the Fruit Sales table on country:

Country

| Country ID | Country | Fruit Producer | Meat Producer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK | yes | yes |
| 2 | Netherlands | yes | yes |
| 3 | Portugal | yes | yes |
| 4 | Andorra | no | no |

FruitSales

| Country ID | Fruit | Sales | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Strawberries | 100 | Jan 21 |
| 1 | Strawberries | 80 | Dec 20 |
| 1 | Apples | 2000 | Jan 21 |
| 2 | Strawberries | 50 | Jan 21 |
| 2 | Pears | 100 | Jan 21 |
| 2 | Pears | 100 | Dec 20 |
| 3 | Pears | 80 | Jan 21 |
| 3 | Pears | 50 | Dec 20 |

[image]

Now you want to create a dashboard that shows you a card with the total sales, the sales previous month and a table with the detail.

I'll just make the measures simpler, but let's say:

```
Sales Current Month = CALCULATE(SUM('Fruit'[Sales]), 'Fruit'[Month] = "Jan 21")

Sales Previous Month = CALCULATE(SUM('Fruit'[Sales]), 'Fruit'[Month] = "Dec 20")
```

[image]

Also if you filter on a particular fruit (let's say Apples), you get this:

[image]

So this doesn't look nice, and your client asks you to put in 0 instead of a blank for previous month sales, so you update the measure (either of your options is ok).

```
Sales Previous Month = CALCULATE(SUM('Fruit'[Sales]), 'Fruit'[Month] = "Dec 20") + 0
```

[image]

Notice what happens here, because now the measure always returns 0, it is showing 0 against lines that don't even exist.

So you might want to do it, but always consider how that measure might be used elsewhere and if it can create issues like the above.

There is one way to fix it in this example, which is validating that there are valid rows, I would do it like this:

```
Sales Previous Month = 
VAR salesCurrentMonth = [Sales Current Month]
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM('Fruit'[Sales]), 'Fruit'[Month] = "Dec 20") + 
   IF(ISBLANK(salesCurrentMonth), BLANK(), 0)
```

[image]